# Red main.storyboard in Copy Bundle Resources

Tags: nsautoreleasepool, xcode5.1

When I try to play the simulator it crashes and sends an error in thread 1. I checked the Copy Bundle Resources and I found out that the story board is in red ink, I don't know if that is the problem but I already tried to erase it and add it again but it stays the same.